# Cluster definition in vcovHC

Tags: r, panel-data, standard-error, plm

I'm running a regression in R's `plm` package similar to this post [Clustered standard errors in R using plm (with fixed effects)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155638/clustered-standard-errors-in-r-using-plm-with-fixed-effects). I.e. panel data with fixed effects and the within-model from `plm`.

My Question is the following: I'm trying to figure out how to cluster my standard errors according to a different variable than the variable called state from the dataset `Cigar`, which is seemingly automatically used by the `cluster = 'group'` option in `vcovHC`. Specifically, if I e.g. have a variable called `id`, how can I tell `vcovHC` to use it as my cluster?

A very related question is the process of how `vcocHC` is selecting the variable for clustering, is it always just the first column in the dataset?

Comment: I removed `clustering` tag. Please be attentive selecting tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you fit a `plm()` you declare a certain set of indexes for cross-section group and time, respectively. When you call `vcovHC(..., cluster = "group")` subsequently, the grouping variable specified in the original `plm()` call is used.

So it seems you only have to use `plm(..., index = c("id", "time"))` instead of `plm(..., index = c("state", "time"))` or something along those lines.