# R plm cluster robust standard errors with multiple imputations

Tags: r, multiple-imputation, difference-in-difference, clustered-standard-errors, plm

I am looking for a way to implement (country) clustered standard errors on a panel regression with individual fixed effects. That is, in `plm()` I want to define some `individual_id` variable as index, but I want another variable called `country` to be the clusters for my cluster robust standard errors. All while working whith multiple imputations.

I have found a package named `bucky` with the function `mi.eval()` which looks promising. It wraps around another R function and implements it for multiple imputations. It even comes with its own cluster option, but for me, it does not work somehow.

```
#first split data set by implicate_number
data.list <- split(as.data.frame(data), factor(data$implicate_number))

#define model
m1 <- y ~ country + time + country*time

#estimate
result <- mi.eval(plm(m1, data = imputationList(data.list), 
                     index = "individual_ID", 
                     model = "within"),
                 robust = TRUE,
                 cluster = country
)
Error in UseMethod("estfun") : 
   no applicable method for 'estfun' applied to an object of class "c('plm', 'panelmodel')"
```

However, it works when I leave the `cluster` argument complete out. The error message must therefore have something to do with the `cluster` argument.

I thought of trying to wrap the `mi.eval()` around some function like `coeftest(plm(...), vcov=vcovHC(plm(...), cluster="group"))` but I see here two problems:

- As `vcovHC()` allows only for `"group"` or `"time"` as options for the `cluster` argument, I would need to include `country` as index in `plm()`, as stated [in the answer to this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205604/cluster-definition-in-vcovhc/205607), which I don't want: I want countries to be explicit parts of the model in order to interact them with time. (The whole thing is a diff-in-diff setting.)
- It doesn't work anyway:

```
mi.eval(coeftest(plm(m1, data = imputationList(data.list), 
             index = "individual_ID", 
             model = "within"), 
         vcov=vcovHC(plm(m1, data = imputationList(data.list), 
                         index = "individual_ID", 
                         model = "within"),
                     cluster = "group")))

Error in mi.eval(coeftest(plm(m1, data = imputationList(data.list), index = "individual_ID",  : 
  Must use "data" option for multiple imputation.
```

So, my question is: Where is my mistake? Do you know another way to pair a panel regression with individual fixed effects, clustered standard errors and multiple imputations in R?

I am thankful for any hint that could help me here :-)

PS: I found it very strange `vcovHC()` is not flexible to use a **different** variable for cluster robust SE than those used in `plm()` as index. Is my idea of doing diff-in-diff with country and time while employing `plm()` only to absorb individual fixed effects so far off?

Cheers!